# How to properly terminate child processes with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a few callback functions and I'd like to launch as multiple processes and have them all terminate via signal from the parent process.

My current way of doing this is creating a shared c_bool with `multiprocessing.Value` and setting it to `True`, then distributing it to all of my processes when they are created. My processes all run a while loop using the shared bool like so:

```
while myC_bool: ...keep running...
```

I can then just switch the bool to `False` from my parent process and all child processes will complete their final loop and exit.

I've been told by many people, and have read in the docs that one should try avoid using shared memory when using multiprocessing.
I was told the best way to avoid this is to daemonize the process, give it a custom signal handler and send it a sigint/sigterm/etc...

My question is, is exclusively using the bool to keep a loop alive and ONLY ever alter it's value from my parent process, and read it from multiple child processes a suitable solution to make all of my child processes terminate quickly and safely? I feel like there is less overhead for all the children to just look at the one shared bool, than to send x number of sigints to them.

Would daemonizing be a better solution? If so I'd like some help understanding why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a lot of good reasons to go with your solution:

- It's easier to think about than signals.
- It's got fewer cross-platform issues to deal with.
- You've already got code that works this way.
- It makes it easy to add a "graceful shutdown" mechanism if you want to in the future.

… and so on.

Keep in mind that, unless you can prove to yourself that `multiprocessing` and the underlying OS primitives, on every platform you care about, are guaranteed to work without synchronization here, you need to put a `Lock` or something else around every access to the shared bool. That isn't exactly complicated, but… once you've done that, using, e.g., an `Event` without the shared bool might be even simpler.

At any rate, if any of those were your reason, I'd say great, do it that way. But according to your question, you actually chose this because of performance:

> I feel like there is less overhead for all the children to just look at the one shared bool, than to send x number of sigints to them

If that's your reason, you're almost certainly wrong. The children have to look at the shared bool (and acquire the shared lock!) every time through some loop, while a signal only has to be sent to each child once. So, your overhead is almost certainly going to be much higher this way.

But really, I can't imagine the overhead of sending one signal per child process, or even grabbing an interprocess lock once per loop per process, is anywhere close to a bottleneck in any useful program, so… why does the overhead even matter here in the first place? Do what makes the most sense in the most simple way.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate the critique on the method I'm using. I had overlooked the fact that even though they are in different processes, they must still acquire a lock to view the value. Am I correct in thinking a reason to avoid shared values is because it makes the processes more thread-like, hindering some of the advantages of using multiple processes?

Comment: @LISTERINE: I never thought of it that way, but yeah, that's a good way to look at it. The major disadvantage to threads is that shared (mutable) values are harder to reason about than message passing, and concurrent programming is hard enough without thinking about races. The CPython-specific disadvantage is that the GIL means threaded code is inherently over-synchronized and ends up nearly serial instead of parallel. Explicit shared values aren't as bad as implicit sharing, and a lock around one value isn't as bad as the GIL, but they're steps back toward the disadvantages of threading.

Comment: @LISTERINE: … That being said, it's worth mentioning that these features exist for a reason: Sometimes starting with multiprocessing and taking one step toward threading is a much better answer than (a) starting with threading and trying to move away from it, or (b) reorganizing your entire algorithm so it can be coded without sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are careful about who modifies the shared variable, it should be fine.

There are many different solutions possible. E.g. use a [`multiprocessing.Event`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event), and have the processes terminate when it is set.
Or using `multiprocessing.Connection` objects (from Pipe). The latter could be used for two-way communication between parent and children. Like a signal to the children to stop, followed by a confirmation to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The people who tell you "don't do this" are wrong.  The point of shared memory is to share memory among multiprocessors and that's exactly what you are doing.

You have a solution that 1) is simple, and 2) works.  The signal/daemon approach is 1) really cool and 2) harder to code correctly and 3) much harder to understand.

The only pitfall I see in your approach is the possibility that a process could see a stale copy of the bool from the CPU's cache, and be delayed slightly in shutting down.  There are ways to flush cache to ensure that this is not happening, but you probably don't need them because for most applications the cache flushing happens often enough automatically.

Stand your ground.

Comment: You really shouldn't just trust "for most applications the cache flushing happens often enough automatically". If you don't know for sure that it happens often enough (or ever!) for your application on every platform you care about, you need to explicitly synchronize. Otherwise, you're pretty much guaranteeing that your code will crash on the first big demo, or that you'll be spending weeks chasing down heisenbugs that only happen on a few users' machines (and of course they'll be the users who have no clue how to submit useful bug reports).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I wasn't aware the pitfall you mentioned was even a complication I could encounter. Looks like I may have some more research to do.