# Kill process using another process python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a script in Python. The idea is to start 3 processes, 2 of them constantly print a message, and the third is there to kill them after a few seconds. The problem is that I don't know how to tell that third which processes should be terminated.

```
from multiprocessing import *
import time

def OkreciLevi():
   while 1:
       print "okrecem levi"
       time.sleep(3)

def OkreciDesni():
   while 1:
       print "okrecem desni"
       time.sleep(3)

def Koci(levi,desni):
   for vrednost in range(2):
       print str(vrednost)
       time.sleep(3)
   levi.terminate()
   desni.terminate()
   print "kocim"

if __name__== '__main__':
   levi=Process(target=OkreciLevi)
   desni=Process(target=OkreciDesni)
   koci=Process(target=Koci, args=(levi,desni))
   koci.start()
   levi.start()
   desni.start()
   levi.join()
   desni.join()
   koci.join()
```

Comment: Also, why can't you use a Queue, or 2 Queues?

Comment: I am Serbian, and used to write names of functions in Serbian. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're on *nix-like operating system I guess that you need to:

1. [Get the PID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192611/2361497) of the multiprocessing worker;
2. Send `SIGTERM` to them. For instanse use `os.kill`.

Also [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752078/how-to-properly-terminate-child-processes-with-multiprocessing-in-python) may be useful for you.

Comment: I tried with SIGTERM but it didn't recognize signal.SIGTERM so i thought if there is another way to do that. The other problem was getting PID from processes levi and desni to process koci.

Comment: @JaSamSale, Post your code to any online service (http://pastebin.com/ for instance) and we'll try to find a workaround.

Comment: I found a way to work around it, but now I wanna know why this doesn't work.